# Draw transparent png image to pdf using pdfbox and seeing gray halo around the edges

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to draw the transparent png onto the Pdf using PdfBoxGraphics2D.

I am using PdfBox version - 2.0.28

```
pdfBoxGraphics2D.drawImage(image, transform, null);
```

and I am overriding the encodeImage() method of PdfBoxGraphics2DLosslessImageEncoder as below

```
pdImageXObject = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bufferedImage);
                    if (imageKey != null) {
                        ((PdfResourceCache) document.getResourceCache()).addImageToCache(imageKey, pdImageXObject);
                    }
```

and we are seeing transparent PNG images appear in PDFs with gray halo around the edges like below. Any help on the fix is greatly appreciated.

[image]

and here are the transparent png images I am trying draw onto the pdf.

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thank you @KJ. Which software/tool you used to see/detect the grey areas from the image.?.

Comment: Thank you @KJ. The issue still exists, please see the PDF in this link -> https://filetransfer.io/data-package/Grsj3za2#link

Comment: @KJ We use imageMagick as a image validation library, it validates the images when we are uploading them into our software and we use PDFBox to render the Pdf's. Can we do anything to fix it on the Pdf or to clean the dirty data from the images?

Comment: Thanks @KJ. Can you please let me know more about the acrobat DC setting you are mentioning ?

Comment: Interesting, the problem happens with Adobe Reader (depending on the zooming) but not with PDF.js and not with PDFBox rendering.

Comment: The source PNG doesn't have the light pink color continued into the transparent areas, there is black. If you use a PNG which is stored with that light pink in the transparent areas, you don't get those rendering artifacts.